# Python Unittest for big arrays

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, numpy, bigdata, python-unittest

I am trying to put together a unittest to test whether my function that reads in big data files, produces the correct result in shape of an numpy array. However, these files and arrays are huge and can not be typed in. I believe I need to save input and output files and test using them. This is how my testModule looks like:

```
import numpy as np
from myFunctions import fun1
import unittest
class TestMyFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.inputFile1 = "input1.txt"
        self.inputFile2 = "input2.txt"
        self.outputFile = "output.txt"

    def test_fun1(self):
        m1 = np.genfromtxt(self.inputFile1)
        m2 = np.genfromtxt(self.inputFile2)
        R = np.genfromtxt(self.outputFile)
        self.assertEqual(fun1(m1,m2),R)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

I'm not sure if there is a better/neater way of testing huge results.

Edit:
Also getting an attribute error now:

```
AttributeError: TestMyFunctions object has no attribute '_testMethodName'
```

Update - AttributeError Solved - 'def **init**()' is not allowed. Changed with def setUp()!

Comment: Is the hugeness an important part of the test? If not, consider making the inputs *not* huge.

Comment: The users would like to test using their own inputs (which are huge experimental results) and they wish not to change much in files (i.e. making it shorter, etc).

Comment: Save them as `.npz` files and load them for test.

Comment: Looks like `fun1` is your function, and that it takes 2 arrays and produces a third.  It's `genfromtxt` that's doing the reading, right?  Depending on `dtypes`, the `unittest.assertEqual` might not be the right test.  I haven't used it in a while, but I expect it requires a simple True/False equality.  But array equality tests produce a boolean array.  And don't work reliably when comparing floats.  Make sure the testing works with small arrays first.

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks. I will try it as soon as I get rid of the attribute error. I don't understand these attribute errors :(

Comment: @hpaulj You were right! I have also tried `assertSequenceEqual, assert_array_almost_equal, assertListEqual, assertTrue(fun1(m1,m2) == R).all(), np.isclose(R,fun1(m1,m2),rtol=0.001).all(), np.array_equal(R,fun1(m1,m2))`. Nothing seem to work! :/